# How to show items that start with character first than items contains that character in autocomplete jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Example : - If I have 2 words in array say

var data = ["abc","cde"]

When I type charcter 'c' then I want cde to be on top of autocomplete list than abc.

Comment: And your attempt to solve the same?

Comment: @HappyCoder I am just using autocomplete plugin for this But Do i need to made custom searching logic for this